# Finding the volume with triple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

I want to find the volume of a function described by:
$$ G= \{(x,y,z)|\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le z \le 1, (x-1)^2+y^2 \le 1\}$$

This question can be best solved in cylindrical coordinates. So if I follow that process, I get the following limits:
$$ r \le z \le 1$$
$$ 0 \le r \le 2\cos(\theta)$$
$$ -\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I am fairly certain that these limits are correct. So continuing, to find the volume of G:
$$\begin{align}
\iiint r \ dz\ dr\ d\theta
&= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \int^{2\cos(\theta)}_{0} \int^{1}_{r} r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta\\
&= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \int^{2\cos(\theta)}_{0} r-r^2  \ dr \ d\theta\\
&= \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(2\cos(\theta))^2}{2}-\frac{(2\cos(\theta))^3}{3}   \ d\theta\\
&= \pi - \frac{32}{9}
\end{align}$$

Solving the above integral I get a negative answer which does not make sense considering the physical quantity is volume, which has to be positive. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should show how you’re solving the above integral

Comment: LaTeX hint: use `\cos \theta` rather than `cos \theta` to get the operator notation for cosine: $\cos \theta$.

Comment: $G$ is not a function, it is a subset of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 3):

Your limits are not completely correct. Note that it should be
$$0 \le r \le 2\cos(\theta)\quad\textbf{and}\quad 0 \le r \leq 1$$
that is the upper limit is $1$ for $|\theta| \le \frac{\pi}{3}$ and it is $2\cos(\theta)$ for $\frac{\pi}{3}\leq|\theta| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore, by symmetry,
$$\begin{align}
V&=2\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{0} \int^{1}_{0} (r-r^2) \ dr \ d\theta+2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int^{2\cos(\theta)}_{0} (r-r^2)  \ dr \ d\theta\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{9}+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{32}{9}\approx 0.439.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your limits of integration aren't quite right. Since $r \leq z \leq 1$, it follows that $r \leq 1$. But your limits for $r$ exceed $1$. Here's a picture of the domain in the $(x, y)$-plane. It's the intersection of two overlapping circles, each of which is centered on the the other.

[image: Overlapping circles in the plane.]

If you're going with cylindrical coordinates, you probably want to exploit symmetry and double the integral for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, you'll have to break it into the sum of two integrals:
$$
0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is your domain:
[image: domain]
You should be inside the red cylinder, above the cone, but below the teal plane. So start with $z$, then calculate $r$, then calculate the angle range:

- $z$ varies from $0$ to $1$
- $r$ varies between $0$ and $z$
- For $\theta$ we need to calculate intersections of the circle of radius $r$ with the off axis circle:
  $$x^2+y^2=r^2\\(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$
  Subtracting the second from the first and expanding the square, you get $$x=\frac{2^2}2$$
  If you write $x=r\cos\theta$, you get $$\cos\theta=\frac r2$$Therefore the limits of $\theta$ are $\pm\arccos(r/2)$